# How to restrict read permission for users in mailbox outlook

Tags: outlook, user-permissions, restriction, mailboxer

In outlook i want to create the mail box which is like common mailbox e.g support.xyx.com so that many people can send mails to that common mailbox, i want to give permission to some users to that mailbox where the users can able to see only To, From and Sub, they should not see the body of the mail.

Is there a way to restrict to read body of the mail? only From, To and Sub where the user can able to see.

I read some of the links which says give reviewer permission (https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/permissions.htm) but reviewer permission will give read only permission, i want to restrict read permission for mail body, the permission should allow user to see only from, To, Sub it should not allow users to see the body of the mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook doesn't provide anything for that out of the box. You can develop a COM add-in where you can replace the default UI by placing [Outlook form regions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/creating-outlook-form-regions?view=vs-2019) or just subclassing the Outlook windows.

Comment: Did you have a chance to look at the link I've mentioned?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42352369/replacing-part-of-outlook-clients-window-with-a-custom-form

Comment: thank you, by using OOB only client wants to do this